# IDE for web development

Tags: web-development

Which IDE is the best for web development in your opinion?

I allready use Sublime text but im trying to find a better one.

Comment: Sorry, [the question in its current form is too broad](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/what-to-do-with-these-cross-platform-development-environment-questions-are-th). If you can make a specific list of requirements it would be OK. Please read [What is required for a question to contain enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Static site? Corporate website? SPA? Databases? When I make 404 pages the best IDE for me is Notepad and Photoshop.

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to use? java/jsp or nodejs or golang based apps?

Answer (score 1):

I use and love [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). There isn't much you can throw at this that it can't handle - especially with all of the available plugins.

If it's too expensive for you, the [early access preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/) is free to use, but it does force you to keep updating every few weeks.

Comment: What if OP needs to work with databases?

Comment: WebStorm Pro (at least) has inbuilt database management tools. Pretty sure that would also be in the EAP.

Comment: What's a Pro version of Webstorm? I have their "All Products Pack" subscription, they do not offer "Pro" versions of any of their software, except for PyCharm but just to distinguish it from its Edu and Community editions. And as they stated on their bug track platform last year: "As you may have already noticed, now, if you have an **active DataGrip or All Products Pack subscription**, you can install and use the Database Tools and SQL plugin in WebStorm 2018.2 that was released on Monday."

Comment: I didn't know whether or not there was a community version of webstorm - I usually use pycharm, which is why I got confused about their license model. I also have the all products pack.